# How to place Remote JSON data into Android array?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pull a set of JSON arrays from a remote URL, but for some reason I keep getting force closed. Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

**My remote JSON URL outputs:**

```
[ { "title": "name1", "url": "http:\/\/radio.shoutcast.com\/fm", "location": "usa", "webtitle": "\u0111i kh\u00f4ng em y\u1ec7u?", "weburl": "http:\/\/www.cnn.com" }, { "title": "MSNBC", "url": "http:\/\/radio.cnn.com\/cnn", "location": "usa", "webtitle": "kh\u00f4ng \u0111i \u0111\u00e2u", "weburl": "http:\/\/www.espn.com" } ]
```

**So in my java code, I have this:**

```
    public void createRadioListForRadioScreen(TableLayout UIRadioList,  ArrayList<String> userRadios, TextView radioListName, TextView radioListLocation) {
    ArrayList<RadioListElement> radioArray = new ArrayList<RadioListElement>();
    MainActivity.getDataManager().loadStoredRadioStations(radioArray, userRadios);
    radioArray.add(new RadioListElement(context, "106.3 FM", "www.cnn.com", "http://radio.cnn.com/cnn"));


    UIRadioList.removeAllViews();
    RadioList radioList = new RadioList(context, radioArray, UIRadioList);
    radioList.addRadioStations(radioListName, radioListLocation);

}
```

I just want to load the necessary fields into the current array. I already declare this on the mainactivity.java

```
String TAG_TITLE = "title";
String TAG_URL = "url";
String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
String TAG_WEBTITLE = "webtitle";
String TAG_WEBURL = "weburl";
String title, url, location, webtitle, weburl;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> radList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();;
```

**CODE to PULL JSON**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {

            JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.url));
            Log.e("MainActivitty", json.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                url = c.getString(TAG_URL);
                location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                webtitle = c.getString(TAG_WEBTITLE);
                weburl = c.getString(TAG_WEBURL);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_URL, url);
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                map.put(TAG_WEBTITLE, webtitle);
                map.put(TAG_WEBURL, weburl);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                radList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please help me bring this URL into my code, thank you so much!

Comment: Can't get anything what you have asking where are you getting `json` data ??? in which variable???

Comment: Could you show the code that pull the json data?

Comment: @zzas11 I am able to pull it just fine... i just don't know how to put it in my current array along with the static field... I also added the code that pulls the json..

Comment: @Clairvoyant my current code has a static array `radioArray.add(new RadioListElement(context, "106.3 FM", "www.cnn.com", "http://radio.cnn.com/cnn"));` now I want have a few more of these from my external url source that I pulled from... I just want to add those into the mix...

Answer (score 0):

Update the code with this

```
for (int a =0; a<radList.size();a++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> tmpData = (HashMap<String, String>) radList.get(a);
        Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
        Iterator it = key.iterator();

        String title;
        String url;
        String location;
        String webtitle;
        String weburl;

        while (it.hasNext()) {   
            title = tmpData.get(TAG_TITLE);
            url = tmpData.get(TAG_URL);
            location = tmpData.get(TAG_LOCATION);
            webtitle= tmpData.get(TAG_WEBTITLE);
            weburl = tmpData.get(TAG_WEBURL);
            it.remove();
        }

        radioArray.add(new RadioListElement(context, webtitle, url , weburl));

}
```

> I didnt test the code but it should give some idea to solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this... I have the static array in a different java file/class not in the main activity... your samples above goes into the stations.java which has the 1 static array i have... but my declare and pulling code is in main_activity.java...

Comment: Either you make `radList` accessible from main_activity.java by making public or move your pulling code to stations.java if the list is not shared with others class

Comment: right, I have a huge learning curve... how do I go about making `radList.add(map);` public?

Comment: In main_java.activity add this code `public ArrayList<String,String> getRadList(){return radList;}`

Comment: I get this error `Incorrect number of arguments for type ArrayList<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>` also, what do you put in between `radioArray.add(new RadioListElement(context, "106.3 FM", "www.cnn.com", "http://radio.cnn.com/cnn"));


    UIRadioList.removeAllViews();` ?

Comment: what is your radList actually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82907/discussion-between-thevoipman-and-zzas11).

Answer (score 0):

did you check the response ?
if not please check the response and debug it using breakpoint to know where cursor has exactly reached and press f8 and check if the data available for you or not.

If this helps you please let me know